# Pipe long running process to clipboard on mac

Tags: bash, osx

I have a seemingly long running process (the lg cli debugger) and when I run it it prints out a uri to access the spawned debugger. I'd like to pipe this to my clipboard (pbcopy on mac) so I don't have to copy it each time. I've tried `ares-inspect -d BigAssTV -a com.atlas.tv | pbcopy` but that just fails with no output. I've tried echoing it to a file and that too fails - but piping it into grep or cut both work (but again piping this output fails)

Comment: I not familiar with your command but it seems as if the output is going to standard error. Try- `command options arguments 2>&1 | pbcopy`.